# How to efficiently delete remainder of a line in vim editor

Tags: vim

I want to delete the part after the cursor position in a line in `vim`. For example, a line looks like that:

```
abcdefghijklmn
```

And the position of a cursor is in character `c`, I want to delete characters starting with `d`. In other words, I want to delete `defghijklmn` and leave `abc`. How can I use `vim` command gracefully?

PS: Currently I just keep pressing the `Backspace` key.

UPDATE:
How to delete from cursor position to the `begining` of the current line?

Comment: That's a very abstract example, and you didn't tell how you would do it; i.e. what Vim commands you already know. That makes it hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I just use `Backspace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**l** (letter ell) moves one character to the right

**D** deletes until the end of the line

**de** deletes until the end of the word

so it depends exactly what you want if it is a complete line the **lD** otherwise **lde**

Comment: The question is a little imprecise, but is simple to answer. You probably should invest half an hour on vim basics though - basic moves and editing aren't that tough.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Vim (and its navigation and editing commands), you should spend 30 minutes on the `vimtutor` that comes with it. Then, there are several good resources, cheatsheets, and vi / Vim tutorials out there on the net. http://vimcasts.org/ has several short entertaining episodes that go beyond the basics.

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 1):

`dt[char]` - Delete from cursor position to `[char]`.

`cw` - Change word (delete word and enter insert mode).

`dw` - Delete a word.

`d3w` - Delete 3 next word.

`x` - Delete the character under the cursor.

`D` - Delete from cursor position to the end of the current line.

From this [source](http://bencrowder.net/files/vim-fu/#deleting)

Answer (score 1):

`d$` will delete from your cursor (including the character under it!) to the end of the current line and also

`d^` will delete from your cursor (keeping the letter under the cursor) to the start of the current line.

In your case `ab[X]defghijklmn`, where [X] is the cursor, move the cursor right by one and type `d$`.